# dockerized cassandra: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Tags: docker, cassandra

I have cassandra docker container, which did not start after hard restart pc.

The command line output is very long. This are some snippets

`java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space`

```
ERROR 20:08:26 JVM state determined to be unstable.  Exiting forcefully due to:
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Caused by: java.io.IOException: Corrupt (negative) value length encountered

ERROR 20:08:29 JVM state determined to be unstable.  Exiting forcefully due to:
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
        at org.apache.cassandra.utils.WrappedRunnable.run(WrappedRunnable.java:28)ERROR 20:08:29 JVM state determined to be unstable.  Exiting forcefully due to:
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
ERROR 20:08:29 JVM state determined to be unstable.  Exiting forcefully due to:
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
ERROR 20:08:29 JVM state determined to be unstable.  Exiting forcefully due to:
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
ERROR 20:08:29 JVM state determined to be unstable.  Exiting forcefully due to:
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
ERROR 20:08:29 JVM state determined to be unstable.  Exiting forcefully due to:
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
ERROR 20:08:29 JVM state determined to be unstable.  Exiting forcefully due to:
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
ERROR 20:08:29 JVM state determined to be unstable.  Exiting forcefully due to:
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
ERROR 20:08:29 Unknown exception caught while attempting to update MaterializedView! findkita.kitas
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
ERROR 20:08:29 Unknown exception caught while attempting to update MaterializedView! findkita.kitas
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
ERROR 20:08:29 Unknown exception caught while attempting to update MaterializedView! findkita.kitas
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
ERROR 20:08:29 Unknown exception caught while attempting to update MaterializedView! findkita.kitas
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
WARN  20:08:29 ConcurrentMarkSweep GC in 5961ms.  CMS Old Gen: 885922704 -> 895736336; Par Survivor Space: 18224024 -> 0


ERROR 20:08:26 Unknown exception caught while attempting to update MaterializedView! findkita.kitas
```

Thats are some of the error I could pick out. But I do not know how to solve theme. Because of error cointainer do not start, so I could not touch cassandra directly.

One error is repead every time:

```
ERROR 20:08:26 Unknown exception caught while attempting to update MaterializedView! findkita.kitas
```

Comment: it looks like it's just mainly out of memory. does the machine have enough memory? do you limit the containers memory allowance? do you set -Xmx of the command?

Comment: no i did not. my pc has 8 gb of ram, when i start docker container it only allocated 2 gb of ram, but there is no limitaion set by me and there is a lots more space in ram.

Comment: Is this on a Mac or Windows dev machine? Or a Linux box?

Comment: I develop on linux using docker to ceap it simular to the live server.